# Best way to remove HTML5 attribute type="number" in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, modernizr

What is the best way to remove type="number" in

```
<input id="s" data-bind="value: s" style="width: 30px" type="number"/>
```

from IE browsers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no need to do this, it will be backwards compatible in IE because off the fallback to `type="text"`